# Android proguard issue

Tags: android, security, proguard

i am asked to do this im my app

Please consider implementing robust code obfuscation techniques to obfuscate sensitive parts of the code, such as:
•   Method names, class names.
•   Strings encryption.
•   Resources Obfuscation.
•   Parameters Obfuscation.
•   Alter the logical flow of the program to make it less predictable.

what should i do ?

solving the problem